# Set animation inside layer-list (one item at the time)

Tags: android, xml, animation, xamarin

I have a `<layer-list>` with four `<item>` inside and on this drawable I have a rotate animation. The rotate animation works well!

The issue is that I really don't know how to make a "zoom in and zoom out" animation on each circle inside the `<layer-list>` **one at the time**. Starting from top-left > top-right > bottom-left > bottom-right > and then repeat.

Anyone?

**drawable/progress_circle.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<layer-list 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="110dp"
    android:bottom="110dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_circle_green_item" />

<item
    android:left="110dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="110dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_circle_green_item" />

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="110dp"
    android:right="110dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_circle_green_item" />

<item
    android:left="110dp"
    android:top="110dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_circle_green_item" />
</layer-list>
```

**anim/progress_circle_rotate.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="2000"
android:repeatCount="infinite">
</rotate>
```

**layout/main.axml:**

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/progress_circle"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**main.cs:**

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation( this, Resource.Animation.progress_circle_rotate );
ImageView progressCircle = ( ImageView )FindViewById( Resource.Id.imageView1 );
progressCircle.StartAnimation( a );
```